# How can I add a navigation bar for multiple brands to the top of my website(s)?

Tags: shopify

I have 3 different brands of physical products. They all share the same prefix (let's say 'ABC') and each brand specializes in something different:

ABC Home
ABC Baby
ABC Travel

All 3 brands are hosted on Shopify. I want a customer to have the ability to bounce back and forth between brands with a navigation bar at the top, similar to Gap, Banana Republic, and Athleta's websites. All 3 of my brands have their own domain and own Shopify site.

It would be great if they could all share the same cart, but if they have to be separate that's okay too.

How can this be done? I am not a professional coder but willing to hire someone if it is complex.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: If you wish to hire a coder to accomplish something, a freelancing website is a better locale than stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to have the same cart as carts are specific to each shop. What type of plan are you on with Shopify? They offer free support if you use one of their themes. I'd imagine it is a fairly easy change.

You'd have to update two files something like this.

theme.liquid (add this at the start of the body tag)

```
<div class="brand_bar">
  <a class="brand" href="http://linkToOtherStore.com">
      <img src="https://linkToImageFile">
  </a>
  <a class="brand" href="http://linkToOtherStore.com">
    <img src="https://linkToImageFile">
  </a>
  <a class="brand" href="http://linkToOtherStore.com">
    <img src="https://linkToImageFile">
  </a>
</div>
```

theme.scss.liquid (or whatever your theme sass file is )(add to the bottom)

```
.brand_bar{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;

}
.brand{
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ffdead;
}
```